# jQuery Plugin: how to access from an event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

Say I have this very basic plugin:

```
(function ($) {

"use strict";

// Namespaced methods.
var methods = {
    init: function (options) {

        return this.each(function () {

            // Default settings.
            var defaults = {
                'sampleText': 'hello'
            };

            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('me');

            // Continue if the plugin hasn't been initialized yet.
            if (!data) {

                $this.mouseup(function () {
                    $this.trigger('onClick'); // events.
                });

                // Add control data.
                $this.data('me', defaults);
                $this.trigger('onLoad'); // events.

            }

        });

    },

    isPlugin: function() {
        return true;
    },

    getData: function() {
        return $(this).data('me');
    }

$.fn.tester = function (method) {

    // Method calling logic.
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test');
    }

};

})(jQuery);
```

And I apply the plugin & monitor the click event like this:

```
$('#poo').tester();
$('#poo').on('onClick', function (e) {
    var $data = e.target.tester('isPlugin');
    var dat = e.target.data('me');
});
```

The problem is; inside the event handling, I cannot access the plugin again. Trying to get both bits of data result in Visual Studio telling me

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'tester'

and...

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'data'

Accessing the plugins data + methods not inside an event works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $data = $(e.target).tester('isPlugin');
var dat = $(e.target).data('me');
```

`e.target` by itself references a DOM node, where you actually want a jQuery object that is using your plug-in.

Comment: Thanks Charlie - that did the trick. Though it had to have been some simple I was missing!